# NginX won't serve static file index.html before go web app

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using `nginx` to serve a go web app running on an `Ubuntu 18.04` server. I want it to respond to the index directive first when I go to `mydomain.com` but in the `nginx` config I have below it is going straight to the web app and ignoring my index.html file. It does work if I get `mydomain.com/index.html` but won't get that file from index. `/var/log/nginx/error.log` has no errors.

The static files are `chown`'ed to `root:www-data` with `chmod 640`.

My static files are at `/srv/static/` and my go web server is at `/srv/web/`

Here is my sites-available config file:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    mydomain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name mydomain.com;

        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

        root /srv/static; 

        index index.html;

        location / {          
           try_files $uri @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
}
```

Comment: This question would fit better on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy; # add $uri/ here
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it returned a directory listing which isn't what I wanted. Maybe I should try it again.

Comment: Are you sure you had the index directive too?
`index index.html;`
Directory listings appear only when no index is found.

Comment: If it still doesn't work try adding `index index.html;` in the `location /` block

Comment: It works now, thanks! I must have tried it before without the index directive.